# Javascript Regex to replace URLs with links, but not in embed (or img) tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using the following code, to search the a div on a page for URLs and replace them with a tags.

However when we have a embed tags within the div it messes up the links within these tags.

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) { 
    return text.replace(/(ftp|http|https|file):\/\/[\S]+(\b|$)/gim,'<a href="$&" class="my_link" target="_blank">$&</a>').replace(/([^\/])(www[^ <]+(\b|$))/gim,'$1<a href="http://$2" class="my_link" target="_blank">$2</a>');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var htmlStr = $("div.content-a").html();
    var htmlStrAfter = replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(htmlStr);
    $("div.content-a").html(htmlStrAfter);
});
```

Can anyone tell be how to perhaps exclude any http://... that are preceded by a " or ' ?

Or similar?

Comment: If you have JavaScript, why not work on the DOM instead of the HTML text? Regex HTML parsing is icky enough and JS doesn't have lookbehind which makes your requirement a little nastier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you should use DOM as recommended. But in order to make your regexp work as desired, you should prepend it with `(?:^|[^"'])`. That means match start of line or match any character excepting `'` and `"`. So first of your regexps will look as follows:

```
/(?:^|[^"'])(ftp|http|https|file):\/\/[\S]+(\b|$)/gim
```

And your chaining of `replace` method is ugly. Code will be much more readable if you will split method invocations to different lines.

Update: And in order to skip first excess character you can use `$1` instead of `$&` and your regexp must be changed to this:

```
/(?:^|[^"'])((ftp|http|https|file):\/\/[\S]+(\b|$))/gim
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what Johannes says...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('div.content').contents().filter(function() {
         return this.nodeType == 3;
       }).each(function(){
             this.nodeValue.replace(/(ftp|http|https|file):\/\/[\S]+(\b|$)/gim,'<a href="$&" class="my_link" target="_blank">$&</a>').replace(/([^\/])(www[^ <]+(\b|$))/gim,'$1<a href="http://$2" class="my_link" target="_blank">$2</a>');
       });
    });
```

***Note the code above is untested but it should look something like that i believe.***

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work even once I changed 'div.content' to 'div.content-a'.

This div will normally contain text and a couple of more divs.

However it also contains a table with an embed tag within it. And an img tag with a URL in the alt (quirk of our system).

Comment: Well then it must not work at all id assume because unless your selector doesnt match anything there should be no difference... What happens do you get any errors?

Comment: BTW - i jsut used your regex - i assumed that worked except for catching urls in tags my code only attempts to miss the tags - if the regex itself doesnt work then perhaps reformulate it Rorick has some good suggestions from what i can tell but im no regex-ninja :-)

Comment: The regex worked, however with your code it seems to filter all tags. The content within the div is not contained within any <p> tags just straight text with an optional inline embed tag.

Comment: That shouldnt do anything to the tags... `contents()` will get all children of the selector including text nodes (the text nodes are what you want) then that if statement should test that the node is a text node (nodeType = 3 = text)... or at least it should... i changed it to use jquery's filter method instead see if that makes a difference.