# Javascript to prepend something to href value of anchor tags only

Tags: javascript, regex

**Requirement**

We have a textarea in our UI where user can enter values like this -

```
<link attr="foo" attr2="bar" href='http://blah.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<a target="something" attr2 ="foobar" href="http://blah.com/test"></a>
```

We would like to prepend {clickurl} to the href attribute of anchor tags **only***, using javascript logic.

**Currently we have the following regex -**

```
return bannerHtml.replace(/(href\s*=\s*[\"'])\s*/ig,"$1{clickurl}");
```

This does the required change, but it does so to any tag containing the href attribute, i.e. not only to anchor tags but also to other tags like link tags. So, the sample input shown above becomes -

```
<link attr="foo" attr2="bar" href='{clickurl}http://blah.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<a target="something" attr2 ="foobar" href="{clickurl}http://blah.com/test"></a>
```

Observed that the change happens to the link tag too.

**So, How do I modify the logic such that -**

- The change happens to anchor tags only.
- it takes into account, the possibility of any number of attributes before the href attribute. (In the sample input, there are many attributes like attr="foo" etc. before the href attribute.)

Is regex advisable here?

I checked some questions like [Javascript Regex to replace URLs with links, but not in embed (or img) tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177142/javascript-regex-to-replace-urls-with-links-but-not-in-embed-or-img-tags?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use something like this :

```
(<a.*?href\s*=\s*[\"'])\s*
```

this will only replace the a tag href.

```
return bannerHtml.replace(/(<a.*?href\s*=\s*[\"'])\s*/ig,"$1{clickurl}");
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/eM7zU9

IMHO it will be better off to just use `getElementsByTagNames('a')` and replace the attr href (Since you want to do it for all the anchors)

Answer (score 0):

To replace urls only in a `<a` tag while also making sure we are just after the `<link` tag, I would suggest this simple replacement:

```
return bannerHtml.replace(/(<link attr[^>]+>[^<]+<a[^>]+?href=")/img, "$1{clickurl}");
```

Comment: @SandeepanNath I am confused, you haven't given us any feedback on the two related questions. Did none of the answers help?

Comment: sorry for the delay. The link tag was there just as an example. There could be any or no tag before after anchor tags.

Comment: By the way, I don't know why both of my questions got downvoted. Since you answered both, I am asking you to let me know the reason in case it were you :). I will update on the other question as soon as I confirm.